# Showing different view on button click and then pass data from child view to parent view in Android

Tags: android

I am creating an application in which I want to have Alarm like functionality. I mean on my parent view there will be a button which on click will show a view where user can take action, then when he clicks on save then the data from the child view is passed to parent view and is shown in listview on parent view. The same functionality how we add new alarm in Android. I am new to android development, so please can somebody point me to some article explaining similar functionality or help me with some code?

Thanks
Ashwani

Comment: if u need code then u need to be specific.. mention what views u want to use as parent and child...

Comment: Yes, it quite possible only you need to learn about dialog implementation in android, if you are unaware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When switching to the child activity, you need to use `startActivityForResult` method (instead of `startActivity`) of your parent activity. This way the parent will be notified when the subsequent activity is finished and returned.

Your child activity should be finished by explicitly setting the result of it (whether it is important: `RESULT_OK` / `RESULT_CANCELED`), and adding the necessary data to the intent's extras (`intent.putExtra(name, value);`). This will be done in the `OnClickListener` of your save button.

To get the notification of the return of child activity, you have to override the `onActivityResult` method of your parent activity. There you can uniquely identify the child activity by the `requestCode` parameter (if you care that to be unique). 
From the `Intent` parameter of this method you can retrieve the extra values passed from the child activity, such as `intent.getStringExtra` or `intent.getSerializableExtra`.